# Load different pictures to one <div> on button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm sorry if this is a easy question but im stuck:
I want to load different pictures in one div box (only one image should be showing at a time) on button click in text.

I'm pretty sure i have Syntax-mistakes since I`m new to Javascript but couldnt find answers that worked on google.

```
function showByUrl(Url)
{
    document.getElementById("my-image").setAttribute('src', Url);
}
```

Then I have the designated div:

```
<div id="my-image" style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:150px;margin-top:50px; ">
```

And one of the buttons to click:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonText" value="Joseph" onclick="showByUrl({Url:https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg});"  />
```

I`d appreciate help! Thanks folks!

Comment: I believe you have to use `img` tag instead of `div`

Comment: use `showByUrl('https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg');` in place of `showByUrl({Url:https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg});`onclick="showByUrl({Url:https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg});"  />`  hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You need an image element to display an image in:

```
<img id="my-image" style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:150px;margin-top:50px; "/>
```

You cannot display an image as a div (think of it as a division, more than a container), you need it in an image. Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) for more info

Answer (score 0):

there are many mistakes, try this:

```
function showByUrl(Url)
        {
            document.getElementById("my-image").setAttribute('src', Url);
        }
```

html:

```
    <img id="my-image" style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:150px;margin-top:50px; " />
    And one of the buttons to click:
```

and

```
  <input type="button" id="buttonText" value="Joseph" onclick="showByUrl('https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg');"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `img` tag instead of `div`
2. `<input type="button" id="buttonText" value="Joseph" onclick="showByUrl('https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg');"  />`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

HTML:

```
<img id="my-image" style="float:left; width:500px; margin-left:150px;margin-top:50px; ">
<input type="button" id="buttonText" value="Joseph" onclick="showByUrl('https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg')"  />
```

JavaScript:

```
function showByUrl(Url){
    document.getElementById("my-image").setAttribute('src', Url);
};
```

working code on JsFiffle:
https://jsbin.com/mugeceguse/edit?html,js

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
showByUrl('https://telebasel.ch/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Josefskirche.jpg');
```

by the time calling the function and also use 'img' tag instead of 'div' for loading the image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks, ended up being a combination of your answers!

I used the img instead of div & i changed to function('http..')

Answer (score 0):

This would be an solution using jQuery:

```
$("input").on('click', function(){
  $('<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png">').load(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#my-image');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/54vfuv4v/